# Replacing deadbolt

Tags: doors, lock, deadbolt

I'm replacing a deadbolt and need help for the next step.  I've installed the exterior portion and I'm now installing the interior portion.  The photo below shows the view from the inside.

The prong sticking out is too long.  I see that there are grooves in the sides of the prong.  Do I just reduce the length of the prong by snapping off a portion at one of the grooves?  If so, is the best way to do this with a couple pair of pliers?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You snap it off along a score with a pair of pliers.

Comment: Yes pliers but use 2 pair, one on either side of the score mark. I have bent the tang just using one